# Local WordPress site is always trying to redirect to "https"

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, ubuntu-14.04

I have configured a `WordPress` site locally from a remote database and project backup which my client has provided.

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` and hence set up the site locally as `local.clientsite.com` and configured properly via `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and by enabling the site. I configured a few sites in the same fashion in the past successfully.

Now the problem is whenever I am running `local.clientsite.com`, it is trying to navigate to `https://local.clientsite.com`.
To prevent this I modified values of `site_url` and `home` in `wp_options` table to use `http://local.clientsite.com`.

**EDIT**
Apart from updating values in `wp_options`, I added the following two lines in `wp-config.php` as well:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://local.clientsite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://local.clientsite.com');
```

**END EDIT**

But still getting the same error.
Someone please suggest a work around for this!

**Content of `/etc/hosts` file**

```
...
127.0.0.1   local.clientsite.com
...
```

**Content of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`**

```
...
<Directory /var/www/wp-projects/clientsite>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

**Contents of both `/etc/apache2/sites-available/local.clientsite.com.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/local.clientsite.com.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ...
   ServerAdmin admin@local.clientsite.com
   ServerName local.clientsite.com

   ServerAlias local.clientsite.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/wp-projects/clientsite
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you please share your plugin directory? Are you use "Really simple ssl" plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused by HSTS - [see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)

So to fix this issue now and to avoid this happening again in the future do not use .com , instead use **.test** for testing/dev purposes

Comment: Thanks! I will try your suggestion, but I always configure my local sites with `.com` and never caught into such an issue. The site was actually started running (`install.php`) when database had no data. Immediately after I restored them, it started happening. Only then I went on making the changes I described above. But the issue is still persisting.

Comment: You can also try clearing the browser cache and cookie. This might fix your redirection issue. .com for the virtual host is not recommended. So, I always use .test or .dev. You can also try methods in this post to disable HSTS - [link](https://really-simple-ssl.com/knowledge-base/clear-hsts-browser/)